# Определение маршрута между двумя точками на сервере

Tags: python, yandex-maps-api, google-maps-api, npm, openstreetmap

Подскажите пожалуйста, может быть кто-то сталкивался с подобными задачами. Необходимо получить длину маршрута между точками на **карте**. По сути нужно получить массив данных на сервер, так же как это приходит в библиотеку Yandex Map или тому подобные. То есть кратчайший маршрут, длина, время и возможность выбрать способ передвижения. Geopy не подойдет, поскольку просто высчитывается расстояние и оно не точное. Если есть какие-то идеи по такой задачи, пожалуйста подскажите. (Язык программирование не важен, но лучше python или node.js) Всем спасибо!

Comment: Дак через апи каких-нибудь карт нельзя такое провернуть ?

Comment: Так вот все карты насколько я понимаю имеют функционал для фронта только. Я бы с удовольствием сделал это хоть через yandex api но актуальной документации как это можно сделать на сервере попросту нет.

Comment: [Здесь](https://yandex.ru/blog/mapsapi/59353) вроде похожий вопрос
[И здесь](https://www.avtodispetcher.ru/distance/export/api) ещё вариант

Answer (score 0):

Это можно реализовать через коммерческий [API Маршрутизатора Яндекс.Карт](https://yandex.ru/routing/doc/router/concepts/about.html)